# How to extract metadata from a Clojure Exception?

Tags: clojure

I'm just starting to learn Clojure and struggling to extract Exception metadata. When I run this:

```clj
(try  
  (/ 1 0)  
  (catch Exception error (println error)))
```

I get an ArithmeticException, as expected. The stacktrace printed looks like this:

```
#error {
 :cause Divide by zero
 :via
 [{:type java.lang.ArithmeticException
   :message Divide by zero
   :at [clojure.lang.Numbers divide Numbers.java 188]}]
 :trace
 [[clojure.lang.Numbers divide Numbers.java 188]
  [clojure.lang.Numbers divide Numbers.java 3901]
  ...
 ]}
```

It looks like a `map` to me, so I tried to extract the value from `:cause` with `(:cause error)`, but it evaluates to `nil`.

How can I do that?

---

### UPDATE:

After digging a bit, I found that `#error {...}` is a [java.lang.Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) class, is that correct?

I tried using Java interop [`(.getCause error)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29), but also returns `nil`. Turns out [`(.getMessage) error)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29) does return "Divide by zero".

Are there other ways to get specific attributes from that class, other than `.getMessage()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clojure has `ex-message` to retrieve the message from an exception and `ex-cause` to retrieve the cause -- if there is one. The printed display of `#error` is a bit misleading here because there actually is no "cause" in the exception (in the Java sense of `.getCause`) because there is no chained exception.

Another useful function is `Throwable->map` which turns the exception (all exceptions are `java.lang.Throwable` at their root) into a regular Clojure hash map on which you can perform all the regular operations:

```
user=> (ex-message (try (/ 1 0) (catch Exception e e)))
"Divide by zero"
user=> (keys (Throwable->map (try (/ 1 0) (catch Exception e e))))
(:via :trace :cause)
user=> (:cause (Throwable->map (try (/ 1 0) (catch Exception e e))))
"Divide by zero"
user=>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the thorough explanation and for pointing out the `Throwable->map` function!